# Selecting an element in iframe with jQuery

Tags: javascript, iframe, getelementbyid

In our application, we parse a web page and load it into another page in an iframe. All the elements in that loaded page have their token IDs. I need to select the elements by those token IDs. Means - I click on an element on the main page and select corresponding element in the page in the iframe. With the help of jQuery I'm doing it in the following way:

```
function selectElement(token) {
     $('[tokenid=' + token + ']').addClass('border'); 
}
```

However with this function I can select the elements in the current page only, not in the iFrame. Could anybody tell me how can I select the elements in the loaded iFrame?

Thanks.

Comment: if anyone need to Access elements of parent window from iframe, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027799/access-elements-of-parent-window-from-iframe

Answer (score 185, accepted):

```
var iframe = $('iframe'); // or some other selector to get the iframe
$('[tokenid=' + token + ']', iframe.contents()).addClass('border');
```

Also note that if the `src` of this iframe is pointing to a different domain, due to security reasons, you will not be able to access the contents of this iframe in javascript.

Comment: Keep in mind $('iframe') doesn't directly return the iframe. You need to pull it out of the array.

Comment: Thanks for the willingness to help. But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @cycero, it should work. Are you generating this iframe dynamically? Don't forget that if you point the src element of this iframe to another domain than your due to security reasons you cannot access its contents.

Comment: I load it not from a different domain but from the same folder. The iFrame contents are being generated dynamically and stored as a file on the server. Then that file is being loaded in iFrame.

Comment: @cycero, I've updated my answer. Try passing `iframe.contents()`

Comment: `$('iframe')` works when I enter this through console, but at debug and at normal execution `$('iframe')` return nothing...

Comment: Oh I found the problem - my script was FROM iframe so I can use usual selectors for iframe.

Answer (score 60):

Take a look at this post: http://praveenbattula.blogspot.com/2009/09/access-iframe-content-using-jquery.html

```
$("#iframeID").contents().find("[tokenid=" + token + "]").html();
```

Place your selector in the find method.

This may not be possible however if the iframe is not coming from your server.  Other posts talk about permission denied errors.

[jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: That works in terms of getting the HTML of the element, but how can I add a CSS class to that selected element? $("#iframeDiv").contents().find("[tokenid=" + token + "]").addClass("border"); doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you get any permission denied errors?  Can you give me the html of the iframe?

Comment: Nope, no permission denied issues.

Answer (score 24):

when your document is ready that doesn't mean that your iframe is ready too,
so you should listen to the iframe load event then access your contents:

```
$(function() {
    $("#my-iframe").bind("load",function(){
        $(this).contents().find("[tokenid=" + token + "]").html();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -6):

If the case is accessing the IFrame via console, e. g. Chrome Dev Tools then you can just select the context of DOM requests via dropdown (see the picture).

[image: Chrome Dev Tools - Selecting the iFrame]

Answer (score -10):

here is simple JQuery to do this to make div draggable with in only container :

```
$("#containerdiv div").draggable( {containment: "#containerdiv ", scroll: false} );
```