# highlight text inside iframe with jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, highlight

I try to highlight text in a page use jquery.highlight-4.js.

```
$('body').highlight('t');
```

My webpage contain an iframe which source on the same domain.

It doesn't work for text inside iframe ( the iframe is on same domain with my web page).

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

`$(iframeID).contents().find('body').highlight(keyword);`
or
`var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
$(iframes[0].contentWindow.document.body).highlight(keyword);`

**And** don't forget to add `.highlight { background-color: yellow }` to the style of the sub-page in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

think you should get the iframe first, like $("#frameID"), then you can manipulate with something in that...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is highlighting the entire `body`, however the content inside the iFrame is not, by most browsers, considered to be in the same `body` as the current document.

In short, $('body') includes everything in the page but things **inside** an iFrame is excluded (due to the awkward nature of iFrame).

Highlight the content by explicitly selecting it using jQuery instead.

I tend to avoid iFrame at all cost. jQuery is pretty powerful in real-time manipulation of HTML contents that I was never really forced to use an iFrame.

Comment: So how can i highlight some text search on iframe?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316979/selecting-an-element-in-iframe-jquery