# JQuery Loading Content of textarea into IFrame

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe

I have an HTML textarea, and an IFrame. On a button click, I would like to be able to load the content of the textarea into the IFrame.

For example, when the user types in `Hello World` into the textarea, and presses the submit button, the text `Hello World` would show up in the IFrame.

Any ideas on how this could be done? Thanks in advance.

**NOTE:** I would like to use JQuery, but I think I'll have to use PHP for this. It sounds more server side.

Comment: I believe the only caveat to this, is that you would first have to have an empty iframe page, like `empty.html`, which would consist of an `<html></html>` tag...I may be wrong. As long as the iframe is then on the same server, you can access the contents and inject whatever html you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target the iframe with jquery only:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
         var content = $("#test").val();
         $('#iframe1').contents().find('p').html(content);
      });
   });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <textarea name="test" id="test" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
   <button id="btnSubmit">Post to iFrame</button>
   <iframe name="iframe1" id="iframe1" src="test2.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Your iframe content page, in this case "test2.html" would have something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
  <p>[intro text or whatever]</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a previous S/O post with a similar issue: [Selecting an element in iFrame jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316979/selecting-an-element-in-iframe-jquery)

Comment: You're right, doesn't seem to like the body tag in find. But if I change that to `.find('p')`, it works as shown here: http://www.reventsoftware.com/test1.html, you can probably use a div instead of p if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = $("#myTextarea").val();
$('#myIframe').contents().find('html').html(content);
```

(edit) ...and #myIframe should initially be:

```
<html></html>
```

Comment: Currently, that's not working. I made a function called inject, and put your code into it. I then made a form, and submit button which called that function.

Comment: Oh - make sure the iframe is pointing to a document on the same domain as your outer html, or you'll won't be allowed to edit the iframe.