# Javascript/jquery : only update content inside div (not outside) - including html and css with live preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not sure if this is possible, but basically I am making a live preview of html and css entered into textarea's and displaying it inside a div (#previewStyle).  I am showing this via javascript/jquery using .keyup

```
$(function(){ 
$(".updatepreview").keyup(function(){
$.post( "<?php echo http() . $websitedomain .'/.../.../styles.php'; ?>", $("#styles_form").serialize(), function(result_data){ $("#previewStyle").html(result_data); /*  use result data here */ }  );
});
```

Here is the problem:  When it loads the css, it updates everything on page (even outside of the div).  Is there any way to limit this using jquery to JUST the div?  I can go in and change all my id's and classes for everything outside of the div if necessary to make sure there is no conflict; however, wanted to check on here for a solution first.  One textarea contains css, one contains html and it serializes them and loads them via the following:

```
<?php echo "
<html>
<head>
<style> ".$_POST['style']."</style>
</head>
<body>".$_POST['html']."</body>
</html>"; 
?>
```

### Update:

The preview div does display correctly; however, the css inside preview div updates and overrides css outside of preview div.  I'm trying to determine if there is a way to limit the css inside preview div to ONLY the preview div and not have it override my main stylesheet for the page around the preview div.

Comment: Use an iframe to keep everything separate from the main document. That's how jsfiddle does it, for example.

Comment: I will try that.  I will post on here if it works/doesn't work correctly.

Comment: but is there any other way to do it with div's?  Just curious.  I'd prefer to use div's if possible over iframe.

Comment: You could change all the CSS selectors to begin with `#divid`, so the effects would be limited to that DIV.

Comment: I changed my div to `<iframe id="previewStyle" style="width: 900px;"></iframe>` to test it, but the above code isn't loading into the iframe?  I've never done this with iframes...am I missing something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292253/jquery-loading-content-of-textarea-into-iframe

Comment: Can you post this as an answer (the iframe comment) and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the contents into an `iframe` so that it will be processed independently of the main document.

See [JQuery Loading Content of textarea into IFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292253/jquery-loading-content-of-textarea-into-iframe) for details on loading HTML and CSS into an iframe.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up switching to iframes; however, now facing resizing iframe.  Got it resizing bigger, but not smaller.  If you know anything about that, can you see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202935/javascript-jquery-auto-adjust-height-of-iframe-how-to-make-iframe-smaller-when