# Get all inputs with type text in console? Page in iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How do you get all of the `inputs` of form on a page into an array while matching by input type(text|checkbox|radio)?

## JavaScript:

Just plain `js` like this will give me ALL of the `inputs`

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName( 'input' );
```

## Now with jQuery:

I have jQuery loaded and I tried: *as per docs* (http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/)

```
$( "<input>" ).is( ":text" ); 
$( "<input>" ).is( "[type=text]" );
```

## Console Error message:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
message: "undefined is not a function"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
```

## Additional information:

The page I am trying to get `text` inputs on is in an iFrame and this whole interaction is running within a webkit.

- My main page has jQuery loaded.
- The iFrame page does not.

Need to get inputs on iFrame page with jQuery from my main page.

Comment: Besides making sure jQuery is loaded, the correct selector would be just `$(':text')`

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/VAL49/

Comment: @roland jquery is not loaded? why is that? I'm using it on the page...

Comment: Also, you don't "need" jQuery to perform selections on text input elements.

Comment: Your last edit just drastically changed the question.

Comment: I didn't realize that iFrame may make a difference here.. I am able to use `$(':text')` in my browser successfully but it fails in the webkit build...

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316979/selecting-an-element-in-iframe-jquery

Comment: Wow coming over from other languages I must say the JS community here seems delightful. Thank you all for the help! :)

Answer (score 5):

To select an input with jQuery you would do this

```
$("input")
```

No brackets needed.

To select all text inputs

```
$("input[type='text']")
```

With the change in the question caused by the edit, you can find the answer here: [Selecting an element in iFrame jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316979/selecting-an-element-in-iframe-jquery)

Comment: That second example doesn't really select all "text inputs". It only selects inputs with `[type='text']`, subtle difference but important.

Comment: @WesleyMurch what's the difference?

Comment: For example it doesn't match simply `<input name="foo">`. Is this really what you're asking though, how to select an input in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

So the given answer is accurate but you can also do

```
$(':text")
```

that will give you the all the text input items, just a little more readable in my opinion.
again the answer from @Robbert is accurate

Answer (score 0):

You select all inputs of type="text" using:

```
$(':text')
```

Inputs of type="checkbox" using:

```
$(':checkbox')
```

Inputs of type="radio" using:

```
$(':radio')
```

**EDIT** To cater for new `iframe` information

Which would, for inputs in an iframe, translate to, respectively:

```
$('iframe').contents().find( ':text' );
$('iframe').contents().find( ':checkbox' );
$('iframe').contents().find( ':radio' );
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question with the new information.

Comment: It does now per the update above.