# I'm unable to perform actions on iframe window

Tags: java, iframe, selenium-webdriver

Below is the site,
    http://www.mortgagecalculator.org/

click on **Get Today's Best Mortgage Rates** & you will get one popup window,which
is there in frame. select **purchase** radio button and click on **search** button.

Here is my code. I am unable to select the radio button with my code. need suggestion. Thanks

```
driver.get("http://www.mortgagecalculator.org/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='calc']/form/section/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/a/strong/font")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.switchTo().frame("brbodxlxcs");
Thread.sleep(4000);
System.out.println("***");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='brTabbedRateTable']/div[1]/form[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/input")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='brTabbedRateTable']/div[1]/form[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li[8]/a")).click();
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Comment: I'm scared to click that link.

Comment: I would recommend using relative xpath(i prefer creating my own), rather than using the absolute one provided by firepath as it is.

Answer (score 0):

There is browser security related to iframes.
You cannot get access to the elements in an iframe like you can other parts of your page.

Others have struggled with this also:
[Selecting an element in iFrame jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316979/selecting-an-element-in-iframe-jquery)

Comment: that means we dont have access to perform actions on iframe in this site?  http://www.mortgagecalculator.org/

Comment: Is mortgagecalculator.org the same domain where your script is running?  If not, then you will not have access.

Comment: yea... Im using the same site

Answer (score 0):

Change `driver.switchTo().frame("brbodxlxcs");` to match something like `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe[title='Fill Quote']")));`

Comment: yea tried with above. still no such element exception

Answer (score 0):

The frame that you are referring to **brbodxlxcs** , seems like id of this frame is dynamically changing.

Try this, its working for me

```
driver.get("http://www.mortgagecalculator.org/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='calc']/form/section/section[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/a/strong/font")).click();
Thread.sleep(8000);
List<WebElement> frames = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("iframe"));
System.out.println(frames.size());
Iterator<WebElement> it = frames.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
      WebElement temp = it.next();
      System.out.println(temp.getAttribute("id"));
 }
```

This gives me all the available frames, in this case its 5.
Then i tried for different frames available one by one & finally got this to work by

```
driver.switchTo().frame(2);
```

also i modified xpath for radio button like

```
 .//*[@id='brTabbedRateTable']//form[@name='mtgSearchForm']//input[@name='loantype' and @value='purchase']
```

& Search button like this,

```
.//*[@id='brTabbedRateTable']//form[@name='mtgSearchForm']//a[text()='Search' and @class='br-submit']
```

I hope it helps !!

Comment: Thanks but still im unable to select the purchase radio button. here is the exception    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (241, 660). Other element would receive the click:

Comment: **Element is not clickable at point (241, 660)** ??     are you using coordinates to click on the element??

Answer (score 0):

It looks the problem you are having is that the iFrame id is dynamic and is different every time the page is rendered. There are two iFrames on the page so use an xpath like to one below to find a specific instance:

```
(//iframe)[2]
```