# Javascript - can't get elements inside one div of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm working with iframes in javascript\jquery and i have one problem, i've tried several technics to get one element, but all had failed. Can you help me please?

This code is in the JSP that renders the iframe content, like this:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        //code goes here
    }
    (...)
</script>
```

[One image -  thousand words http://1drv.ms/1EI0Svs](http://1drv.ms/1EI0Svs)

http://1drv.ms/1EI0Svs

NOTE: 
The element i'm trying to catch is inside one  in the body root
And i can get the parent div, where those elements are

Thank's

**REV ATENTION**: I NEVER SAID I WAS IN DIFFERENT DOMAIN, i said i was exactly at same jsp. As noob i was expecting help and i feel you kick me of. Thanks.

Comment: Is the iframe source a page on the same domain?

Comment: Image link is broken.

Comment: Was going to mark it a dupe with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316979/selecting-an-element-in-iframe-jquery but too slow I see.

Comment: Yes @Halcyon, same domain, and same page - i'm noob but thats strange to me

Comment: Sorry @jonmrich, the image wasn't correct, i was changint it:1drv.ms/1LnuvXG

Answer (score 0):

As long as the iframe is the same domain and the iframe is fully loaded it is as simple as

```
var text = $("#IframeId").contents().find(".YourSelector").text();
```

Comment: Does it really work this way? `:)`

Comment: Sorry, the image wasn't correct, i was changint it:http://1drv.ms/1LnuvXG

Comment: I get the same result as before, that i really can't understand: [width chrome] i see  one empty array [ ], but i can expand and see the result!!! and the len is 0!

Comment: @epascarello, this was the result: http://1drv.ms/1EI0Svs

Comment: no, it didn't @Praveen Kumar :'(

Comment: UM, your image shows that it found one element in the console.... What is that mystery `y` after that?