# Why can't I get elements,e.g. body, inside an iframe as $("iframe body")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have been search for how to add css rules to elements inide an `iframe`. On most of the SO posts they get the inner elements of iframe tag as:

```
$("iframe").contents().find("body");
```

My question is why can't I select the `body` element inside the `iframe` as:

```
$("iframe body");
```

AFAIK `contents` jquery method searches for all the text nodes. But isn't `body` tag an *element* node? Please explain.

Comment: It is forbiden for evident security reasons...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting an element in iFrame jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316979/selecting-an-element-in-iframe-jquery)

Comment: @n00dl3 But then if jquery `contents` can overrule that forbiddeness  then  what is it's advantage?