# Javascript unable to remove DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Actually I am offering an `iframe` to other users from my website that works perfectly but I want to remove a specific **DIV** from it if `iframe` code is used on some other website, I only allowed my site to show specific Div inside `iframe`.

I have already wrote a code that works perfectly on **localhost/xampp** server but this code won't work on live site I don't know what I am doing wrong in it?

Here is my actual code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var frameLocation = window.location.hostname; 
var whiteLocation = "<?php echo $ShowMyDomain; // prints mywebsite.com ?>"; 
if (whiteLocation != frameLocation) { 
$('#adprimary').remove(); 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have any console errors? Have you linked to jQuery correctly on the live site?

Comment: you have no influence on the contents of an iFrame

Comment: @Andy JQuery works perfectly and no errors in console as I said it works on localhost but not on live site

Comment: @Any this code used in frame which is not detecting hostname which uses iframe

Comment: if you do `console.log(frameLocation)`, what do you get? Is it what you expect, or something else?

Comment: iframe means you in different context, check this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316979/selecting-an-element-in-iframe-jquery

Comment: you can try this code hide your div  $('#adprimary').css("display","none");

Comment: @blex `console.log(frameLocation)` doesn't show any thing also  `$('#adprimary').css("display","none");` wont work

Comment: @Andy i got the error its take my hostname but I want to extract domain from `document.referrer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code won't work because the variable `frameLocation` gets your own domain name and match with variable `whiteLocation`. To resolve this issue you must use `document.referrer` function may be in some other variable then extract the domain name from it to and reuse it in `frameLocation`.

You can try this working **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/infohassan/5yy4b2ww/1/)**

or here is the code that will resolve your problem

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var urlGet = document.referrer; 
var frameLocation = urlGet.match(/:\/\/(.[^/]+)/)[1]; 
var whiteLocation = "<?php echo $ShowMyDomain; // prints mywebsite.com ?>"; 
if (whiteLocation!=frameLocation) { 
$('#adprimary').remove(); 
}
}); 
</script>
```