# How to pick element inside iframe using getElementsByTagName or any sector

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, syntax-error, show

I have an iframe which looks like this

```
<iframe name="myframe1" id="myframe1" width="100%" height="100%" src="a.html">
<html>
    <head></head>
    <frameset name="myframe2" cols="0%, 100%" border="0" frameBorder="0" frameSpacing="0">
        <frame name="page1" src="c.html" scrolling="no"></frame>
        <frame name="page2" src="d.html" >
            <html>
                <head></head>
                <body class="top">
                    <div class="div1">
                        <div class="div2">
                            <div class="div3">
                                <ul class="x">
                                    <li>a</li>
                                    <li>b</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>

        </frame>

    </frameset>
</html>
</iframe>
```

I want to refer to the element `x`. I tried in several ways but I couldn't find a solution.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('ads')[0]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    VM257:1 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://www. exampleMY SITE.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
        at <anonymous>:1:57
    (anonymous) @ VM257:1

    document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument.document.getElementsByClassName('ads')[0]

VM626:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http:// exampleMYIFRAME.COM" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at <anonymous>:1:43
```

Comment: The error messages have ... a message, wouldn't you read it?

Comment: possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316979/selecting-an-element-in-iframe-jquery

Comment: I don't used  jQuery

just javascript

Comment: Whatever markup you place between an iframe tag will never render. `<iframe....>` **YOU WILL NEVER SEE THIS** `</iframe>`.If you got this idea from an example, that example is for old browsers that did not support iframes. Every current browser in existence supports the iframe now, so effectively: ***anything placed between an iframe's tags is useless insomuch as a comment*** Mr. Ward is correct about Same Origin Policy the error says: `locked a frame with origin "http://www. exampleMY SITE.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.` Basically, you'll need both pages to be on the same domain.

Comment: can I IMPORT INFO FORM <script>$(document).ready(function(){$('.serversList > li').click(function(){$(".serversList > li").removeClass('active');$(this).addClass('active');$.ajax({url:'http://exam.com/wp-content/themes/Cimaclub/servers/server.php',data:'q=66179&i='+$(this).data('server')+'',success:function(msg){$(".embedServer").html(msg);}});});});</script>

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because of the Same-Origin-Policy on your page.

See [the Same-Origin-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) reference for details and workarounds.

Comment: so can I fix , I need sector

Comment: Vin - I can't answer that question for you. It depends on your server