# How to remove class from div inside iframe contents

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I have this structure, and i want to remove `test2` class from `div`

```
iframe1 -> iframe2 -> <div class="test1 test2">.... </div>
```

I am able to access iframe2 but I am not able to find above div in second iframe.

here what I have tried

```
document.querySelectorAll('iframe').forEach(item => {
            var y = item.contentDocument.body.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
            setTimeout(() => {
                y[0].style.width = '100vw'; 
                $(y[0]).contents().find(".test2").removeClass('.test2')
            }, [500])
        })
```

`y[0].style.width = '100vw';`

this is working. but I am not able to find div with `test2` class

console.log(y[0]) is iframe as expected.

[image]

`y[0].contentDocument` is null

if anyone can help me with this. Thanks in advance

Also in some answers I found that we can't change contents of iframe if it is of cross origin. but here I have same origin.

I just want some css changes either i need to remove test2 class or override it.

Comment: I am using setTimeout because iframe2 is not loading instantly

Comment: luckily we can't. the only possible case requires you to own the parent page and the iframe, in which case you must go through a message system. but in all cases direct access is prohibited.

Comment: You will want to use the correct syntax for `.removeClass()`, you have `'.test2'`. This is not correct. You want to use the Class Name, without the `.`.

Comment: this is also not working. When I tried to do console.log($(y[0]).contents().find(".test))                                                                
 I am getting this.                                                                                             ```S.fn.init [prevObject: S.fn.init(0)]
length: 0
prevObject: S.fn.init(0)
length: 0
prevObject: S.fn.init(1)
0: iframe
```

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, `iframe2` is nested inside `iframe1`, is that correct? If so, you must find and get the Contents of `iframe2` after you find and get the Contents of `iframe1`. Your script does not drill down far enough to find the proper content.

Comment: if you understand the principle that you cannot edit a web page from another web page, you should understand that you cannot edit the content of an iframe, even from its parent page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a mock structure like the following, all with the same Origin:

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <iframe id="iframe1" src="index2.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

**index2.html**

```
<body>
  <iframe id="iframe2" src="index3.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

**index3.html**

```
<body>
  <div class="test2">Foo</div>
</body>
```

You would need the following confusing code.

```
var f1 = $("#iframe1");
var f2 = $("#iframe2", f1.contents());
var target = $(".test2", f2.contents());
target.removeClass("test2");
```

This is based on the following: [Selecting an element in iframe with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316979/selecting-an-element-in-iframe-with-jquery)

Comment: I tried above code, this is not removing class. may be it is due to having multiple classes on div like I mentioned in my question ```<div class="test1 test2">```

Comment: @Abhi no `.removeClass()` is not effected by that. Do you see any Errors in Console when you run the code?

Comment: No errors. when I try to do console.log(target) I am getting something like this ```S.fn.init [prevObject: S.fn.init(0)]```

Comment: @Abhi please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example