# How to append style inside iframe head element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im working on webchat integration using 3rd party library and i want to customize the style.  I want to append the style to head (inside the iframe), I have written the code like below, but it still won't work.

[image]

**Code**

```
$('#qontak-webchat-widget').contents().find('head')
  .append(`<style type='text/css'> #qontak-webchat { background-color: red; } </style>`)
```

Comment: We can not tell with certainty from your screenshot, but I am guessing that _"using 3rd party library"_ most likely means, the iframe itself loads its content from a different origin - in which case you _can't_ manipulate its contents via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery is targeting `$('#qontak-webchat-widget').contents().find('head')`. which is looking for a `head` element that is a child element of the `#qontak-webchat-widget`.

As `head` is a child of `html` and a `sibling` of `body`, you wont be able to locate `head` as you are trying to do it.

Try adjusting your jquery to:

```js
$('head').append(`<style type='text/css'> #qontak-webchat { background-color: red; } </style>`)
```

If you need to modify the `head` located in an iframe, use the technique given [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6316985/51) to access the contents of the iframe.

Comment: if i had multiple head in my source code, how it works?

Comment: Technically speaking, html docs should only have one section. But if you had more than one, you could select the first with `$('body head').first()`. Depends on how you want to identify the

Comment: see my screenshot above, the document is inside body. and there is head. so in one html page there are 2 head tag

Comment: @frankfurt, no, there are not two `head` elements in one document here. The iframe has its _own_ document.