# Access iFrame Elements with JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to access a `<p>` element inside an `iFrame` through javascript and print it's contents in the console. However after multiple attempts it always fails to do so.

Here's the code of the main page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CS3 - Test Page</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js" integrity="sha256-JlqSTELeR4TLqP0OG9dxM7yDPqX1ox/HfgiSLBj8+kM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe id="frame" src="https://cs3.bluenest.it/Website/test.html"></iframe>

    <script>
        //script to access the iframe and print the contents of the p tag with the id='text'
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here's the code of the subpage (test.html) that gets instantiated inside the iframe:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="text"> this text should get printed in the console </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried multiple methods from different sources but they all fail to accomplish my goal:

Method from https://learningjquery.com/2016/09/using-jquery-to-access-iframe-elements

```js
var frame = $("frame").contents();
var element = frame.find("#text");
console.log("content of #text: " + element.html());
```

The variable `element` remains undefined and the console prints "`content of #text: undefined`"

---

Method from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp

```js
var frame = document.getElementById("frame");
var element = frame.contentWindow.document.getElementById("text");
console.log("content of #text: " + element.html());
```

The variable `element` ends up being null and the console prints out the error "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'html')`"

---

Method from [Selecting an element in iframe with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316979/selecting-an-element-in-iframe-with-jquery)

```js
var iframe = $('frame');
var element = $('#text', iframe.contents());
console.log("content of #text: " + element.html());
```

The variable `element` remains undefined and the console prints "`content of #text: undefined`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it's necessary to check that the iFrame content has loaded.

```
$(function () {
  $('iframe').on('load', function () {
    const para = $(this).contents().find('p');
    console.log($(para).text());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could the issue be in the next line:

```
var iframe = $('frame');
```

You're trying to get iframe but only frame is written.
Maybe you should try:

```
    var iframe = $('#frame');
```

or

```
    var iframe = $('iframe');
```

Also, have you checked these answers [How to get the body's content of an iframe in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript)